# How to search entities by an arbitrary field

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Having a `javax.persistence.Query` object how can I manipulate it, or how can I inject in it different searched parameters & values?

I have a `NamedQuery`, and I want to change the query, so that the results are filtered by an entity field & value.

Comment: For the problem of searching by an arbitray field: probably it makes sense to work with Criteria Queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Define another named query with the where clause that suits you, and use that named query instead.